# projects are lost in eclipse workspace after restart

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

I need some help!

I am using eclipse 3.7 and mylyn 3.6.2 with JIRA connector 3.0.2

Sometimes after restart eclipse forgets all the projects in the workspace. Workspace is not totally recreated all the mylyn connections, and java working sets are present, but all the projects are gone.

So I need to re-import them each time this happens.

I am blaming mylyn, because this never happened before I started using it.
And in log file I see that it has some problems on start:

```
!SESSION 2011-10-25 10:34:39.302 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.6.0_23
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core 2 0 2011-10-25 10:34:45.765
!MESSAGE Failed to load tasks.xml.zip, restoring from snapshot
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Task list file contains no data "/home/german/work/irbisenv/javawsp/.metadata/.mylyn/tasks.xml.zip"
     at      org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.core.externalization.TaskListExternalizer.readTaskList(TaskListExternalizer.java:203)
     at      org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.core.externalization.TaskListExternalizationParticipant$1.ex
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my HDD. After formatting everything works fine.